# Rcpp - Use multiple C++ functions in file referenced by sourceCpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I hope this isn't too obvious, as I've searched all day and can't find the answer.

Say I have the following R file:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("cfile.cpp")

giveOutput(c(1,2,3))
```

And it compiles the following C++ file:

```
#include <Rcpp>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector plusTwo(NumericVector x){
  NumericVector out = x + 2.0;

  return out;
}

NumericVector giveOutput(NumericVector a){

NumericVector b = plusTwo(a);
return b;
}
```

No matter what I try, the Rcpp preprocessor makes `plusTwo()` available, and `giveOutput()` not at all. The documentation I've been able to find says that this is the point at which one should create a package, but after reading the package vignette it seems an order of magnitude more complicated than what I need.

Short of explicitly defining `plusTwo()` inside `giveOutput()`, what can I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are expected to use the *export attribute* in front of every function you wanted exported.  So by correcting your file to

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector plusTwo(NumericVector x){
  NumericVector out = x + 2.0;
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector giveOutput(NumericVector a){
  NumericVector b = plusTwo(a);
  return b;
}
```

I get the desired behaviour:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/patrick.cpp")
R> giveOutput(1:3)
[1] 3 4 5
R> plusTwo(1:3)
[1] 3 4 5
R>
```

Oh, and creating a package is as easy as calling `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` (but read its help page, particularly for the `attributes` argument).  I know of at least one CRAN package that started how you started here and *clearly* went via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`...

Comment: Oh, that is rather obvious :) Thanks!
Wonderful package by the way, I'm so excited to abandon C.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's not so obvious. Here's the file I'm trying to implement: http://pastebin.com/bP4kGLs2

inclusionprobabilitiesCpp is recognized and compiles, however UPtilleCpp does not, and after compilation ls() in R only shows the former. Is there a trick when they get longer?

Comment: Confirming -- it also fails on two machines of ours. We will take a closer look.

Comment: Looks like your `//**` was misinterpreted by the parser. It is a bug on our side (misinterpreted as the start of a block comment) but you can avoid it ... by having "more standard" comments such as plain old `//` or even `// **` with a space.

Comment: JJ says this has now been fixed in SVN revision 4242. Thanks for the bug report!